# Optimize single core of a solr server having multiple cores

Tags: solrj, solr4

My solr server is having multiple cores.  Is it possible to optimize a single core of it using solrJ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
public UpdateResponse optimize(String collection){}
```

Being a collection:

> **Collection:** A complete logical index in a SolrCloud cluster. It is associated with a config set and is made up of one or more shards. If
>   the number of shards is more than one, it is a distributed index, but
>   SolrCloud lets you refer to it by the collection name and not worry
>   about the shards parameter that is normally required for
>   DistributedSearch.

And a core:

> **Solr Core:** Also referred to as just a "Core". This is a running
>   instance of a Lucene index along with all the Solr configuration
>   (SolrConfigXml, SchemaXml, etc...) required to use it. A single Solr
>   application can contain 0 or more cores which are run largely in
>   isolation but can communicate with each other if necessary via the
>   CoreContainer. From a historical perspective: Solr initially only
>   supported one index, and the SolrCore class was a singleton for
>   coordinating the low-level functionality at the "core" of Solr. When
>   support was added for creating and managing multiple Cores on the fly,
>   the class was refactored to no longer be a Singleton, but the name
>   stuck.

You can find more information regarding this method and Solr terminology here:
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_2_1/solr-solrj/index.html?overview-summary.html
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTerminology

Hope this helps!